# How to change a Ruby on Rails application name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Ruby on Rails application that was created using:

```
rails new old_name -d mysql
```

Now I want to change the application name to be `new_name`.

Just changing the application folder name will not be enough, because the database name, for example, also has to be changed (from `old_name_development` to `new_name_development`). I wonder if there are other places in the automatically generated files that needs changing.

Is there any built in command for changing the application name ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a Rails plugin to do it for you. Super convenient.

https://github.com/get/rename

Comment: I just used this and it worked well, I hope they keep it up to work with Rails 4, which will not support `vendor/plugins`.

Answer (score 69):

In Rails 3, there are references to the application name in the following files:

- config/application.rb
- config/environment.rb
- config/environments/development.rb
- config/environments/production.rb
- config/environments/test.rb
- config/initializers/secret_token.rb
- config/initializers/session_store.rb
- config/mongoid.yml (if using Mongoid)
- config/routes.rb
- config.ru
- Rakefile
- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, in title tag

Comment: It will also be in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, inside `<title>`

Comment: I have confirmed, this list is accurate for Rails 4 beta 1 as well

Answer (score 9):

in Rails 3, the application class is defined in config/application.rb, and referred to in your environment files (config/environment.rb, config/environments/*.rb) and config/routes.rb.  I think that's it, but you should find out pretty quickly from rails server if you missed one. :)

- config/application.rb
- config/enviroment.rb
- config/environments/*.rb
- config/routes.rb

That said, unless you've got a very specific reason for wanting it changed, I wouldn't bother.  Doesn't really affect the application in any other way.

Comment: The name is so unrelated that I can't live with it :) Thanks for your answer. I think I'll do some sort of `grep` to find out all occurrences.

Comment: I also found it in `/config/routes.rb` and `/Rakefile` and `/config.ru`. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I also found it in `initializers/secret_token.rb` and `initializers/session_store.rb`.

Answer (score 3):

Rails 3 application can rename using https://github.com/morshedalam/rename

Answer (score 1):

Run the following to replace the old_name for new_name from the root of your Rails (3.0.7) project.

```
replace old_name new_name -- ./config/environment.rb ./config/application.rb ./Rakefile ./config/initializers/secret_token.rb ./config/environments/production.rb ./config/environments/development.rb ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb ./config/routes.rb config.ru ./config/environments/test.rb ./config/initializers/session_store.rb
```

But be sure to run

```
fgrep old_name . -iR
```

Or something similar first to check if there are no occurrences of old_name in your project who not should be replaced.

**EDIT:**

Of course for this you need to have the replace command installed.

And take in account that your appname will be CamelCased, so maybe you have to try a few different variations, like OldName vs. NewName.

Answer (score 1):

On rails 4

Add

```
gem 'rename'
```

to Gemfile then do

```
bundle install
```

After bundle install

```
rails g rename:app_to name_of_app
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find yourself having to rename the app when wanting or having to generate a model or scaffold with the same name as the app's name. Just happened to me. Used https://github.com/morshedalam/rename on Rails 3.2.13 and no problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I have used good old shell commands :

```
grep -r old_name * | cut -d: -f1 | xargs sed -i .bak 's/old_name/new_name/g'
```

This command replace the old_name with new_name in all file it finds the old_name. However, it creates a backup file with the extension '.bak'. Those file can be easily removed once you check everything went well.

The advantage of this, is that it is not 'rails version dependent'.