# change name of project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How to change your project name in ruby on rails ?
while u create a project name of project is scattered in below files
   In Rails 3, there are references to the application name in the following files:

```
config/application.rb
config/environment.rb
config/environments/development.rb
config/environments/production.rb
config/environments/test.rb
config/initializers/secret_token.rb
config/initializers/session_store.rb
config/mongoid.yml (if using Mongoid)
config/routes.rb
config.ru
Rakefile
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, in title tag
```

Is there any command to replace the name of project in all these files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383670/how-to-change-a-ruby-on-rails-application-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this follow links below
http://gkunwar1.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/rails-tips/
Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a command to replace the name in all those files. You will need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`rename`](https://rubygems.org/gems/rename)

For Rails 5/4.x

```
#Gemfile
gem `rename`

#Command prompt
rails g rename:into NewAppName
```

For Rails 3

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/get/Rename.git
rails g rename_to SweetNewName
```