# Rails newbie: routing file class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been working on adapting a CS app to a different app. In my routing file, the first line is

`Cs::Application.routes.draw do`

I understand that this is the class definition, but where exactly is the first prefix `Cs` coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cs` is the name of your application. When you make a new rails app, you do:

```
rails new project_name
```

In this case, `Cs` was the project name.

Comment: thanks, found how to change it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383670/how-to-change-a-ruby-on-rails-application-name