# How do I change a Ruby on Rails (4) application name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Essentially I have a basic app that I would like to use as base for my other projects.

I ran `git clone git@site.org:user/app.git newfolder`

But when I run my rails app `rails s` I get the following error:

```
Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.
```

So I run `rake db:migrate` and start the app again, getting the following error:

[image]

I have a sneaking suspicion that it has something to do with the app name as asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383670/how-to-change-a-ruby-on-rails-application-name) but I noticed the solution was provided for Rails 3 and the [GitHub project](https://github.com/get/rename) hasn't been updated in two years.

Essentially, I think I have a solution (renaming the app) but I don't know how to do that. However, I may be wrong and I don't know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because, one of the css files you are requiring in your application.css is requiring application.css. Go through all the file in your app/assets/stylesheets and make sure that none of the file that is required in application.css is requiring application.css.