# How to change the name of a Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rename

I want to change the name on my Rails 4 app.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383670/how-to-change-a-ruby-on-rails-application-name) has a lot of answers for Rails 3, but I want to change the name of the app, and all of it's app name references in Rails 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do the following:

1. **backup**, then make a Git branch along the lines of 'app-rename'
2. rename your app folder to `new_app_name`
3. `rails new new_app_name --force # overwrites contents of your app`
4. add the necessary changes with `git add -p`, editing hunks and staging them as needed.
5. commit, merge the branch and you're done. or checkout your original branch if you messed something up

You're still going through all the files that got overwritten; but the advantage (to me at least) is not having to remember all the classes to rename and/or accidentally missing one. Rails does that for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must go through a variety of file names and change "old_app_name" to "new_app_name". There's is no easy way around this. The second top comment in the link you posted list the file names where the application name is referenced

Answer (score 0):

I did it with RubyMine with the rename feature, in the name of the app. Shortcut shift+f6 and it seemed to work.