# RoR Copy Devise Using Old Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm not too savvy with Ruby on Rails, but I know enough that I was able to copy my app into a slightly altered duplicate. Almost everything is going fine with the new copy except that my user email regex is still using the older copy's user email regex.

I'm trying to figure out which part calls devise.rb in the initializers, but so far I have had no luck. I've also had a hard time finding if others have had this problem and solved it.

**EDIT - I solved my own problem and answered it below.**

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking why the new copy of my app is calling devise.rb from the older version of the app. I want to know where I can go to have it use the devise.rb initializer that is in its proper directory since I want to use different email regex for each app.

Comment: If you *copied* it then it's not doing anything with your old app at all. If you're not using some sort of Ruby version manager, and you're using a system gem, and you modified that gem, then you have multiple problems.

Comment: I found the answer, if you're interested, Dave.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer to my question. The problem is that copying the app meant that I didn't give the application its own application name. This caused the program to refer to the application with the old application name. All I did was rename it and now it functions the way I want.

I used the following post to help me rename: [How to change a Ruby on Rails application name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383670/how-to-change-a-ruby-on-rails-application-name)